# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error on ReportViewerWebControlHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2012

I have been trying from past few days to run Report Viewer in my application but failed.
The problem is that when I add

```
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

this handler in my web.config HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error on every page I try to access.

And if I remove it then it works fine but then the error occur on my reporting page

**Report Viewer Configuration Error**

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add

```
<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add

```
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

Please help me out of this problem

My whole web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="courierdbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=ushupk_courier;User ID= ushupk_ushupk;Password=Fahad123!@#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState timeout="5400" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!--<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />-->
    </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I can't offer an answer because I have what appears to be the same issue - I'm in the process of integrating some SSRS reports into new webpages of an existing webforms application using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.  The changes run fine when running locally in debug mode, but as I was deploying to a VDEV box in preparation for another promotion to a System test environment, I made the addition in the web.config for the httphandler and that caused the 500 internal server error.  When I comment that line back out or remove it from the web.config, the app works again (not the new SSRS reporting features though).  I suspect that I have an issue somewhere in the web.config file as other developers in our org have successfully implemented similar solutions without the issue I see.  We're on V 12 of the ReportViewer.